How to include a LaTeX expression in a web page built with the Matlab Publish?
I want to Publish on a web page a LaTeX expression built with the Matlab latex function. I am using the native Publish button.
I can Publish this expression, only if I write it directly:
% $P(s) = s^3+6\,s^2+11\,s+6$

Is there any way to Publish the same expression, but from a LaTeX variable?
Evenmore, how to Publish the LaTeX variable within a nested HTML code?
I understand it could be not possible, since Publishing is made from a comment line, but, could I built a comment expression from a string?
This is the code I wrote:
%% Publish LaTeX in HTML
% How to publish a variable LaTeX
%% Polynomial
% Define p(x) polynomial, and simbolic and LaTeX strings
syms s
P = [1,6,11,6]       % Defining P(s) polynomial (numeric treatment)
symP = poly2sym(P,s) % symbolic string
pretty(symP)         % display pretty form
ltxP = latex(symP)   % LaTeX string
%% Publish in HTML
% Publishing P(s) in HTML is posible with the direct description of the
% polynomial:
%
% $P(s) = s^3+6\,s^2+11\,s+6$
%
% But, how to publish the same polynomial P(s) from the LaTeX variable?
%
% $P(s) = ltxP$
%
% <html>
% <p style="font-family:Times; font-size:large;">
% Evenmore, how to publish the LaTeX variable within a nested HTML code? is
% this possible?</p>
% <p>$P(s)=ltxP$<br>
%    \(P(s)=ltxP\)<br>
%    $$P(s)=ltxP$$</p>
% </html>


The only way I figure is writing an M-file that builds all the comments.
Something like:
generator.m --> pub.m             --> html
(origin)        (file to Publish)     (Published web page)

My code example, myOwnSolution.m is:
% My own solution
clc, clear, close all
syms s

fprintf('I want to Publish a LaTeX Variable, randomly built.\n');
fprintf('Let''s say:\n');
a = randi([2,7]);
b = randi([2,7]);
P = [1,a,b]; % Coeffs are randomly selected
symPol = poly2sym(P,s);
disp('A pretty view of P(s), in the Workspace:')
pretty(symPol);
fprintf('\n\n')

fileID = fopen('testPublishLaTeX.m','w');

fprintf(fileID,'%%%% Publish a LaTeX variable\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% This is a Publish file in Matlab\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%%%% First Section \n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% Publish a LaTeX variable in a text line: $P(s)=%s$\n',latex(symPol));
fprintf(fileID,'%%%% Second Section\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% Publish a LaTeX variable and expression in a ordered list:\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%%\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% # A LaTeX variable: $P(s)=%s$\n',latex(symPol));
fprintf(fileID,'%% # A LaTeX expression: $F(s)=\\alpha^2$\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%%%% Third Section\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% Publish a LaTeX variable and expression in a unordered list:\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%%\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% * A LaTeX variable: $P(s)=%s$\n',latex(symPol));
fprintf(fileID,'%% * A LaTeX expression: $F(s)=\\alpha^2$\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%%%% Fourth Section\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% Publish a LaTeX variable and expression as lone expressions:\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%%\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% $$P(s)=%s$$\n',latex(symPol));
fprintf(fileID,'%%\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% $$F(s)=\\alpha^2$$\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%%%% Fifth Section\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% Publish a LaTeX variable with (not in) HTML format:\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%%\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% <html>\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% <div style="font-family:Georgia, serif; font-size:large;">\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% <p>This is my polynomial over s:</p>\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% </div>\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% </html>\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%%\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%% $$P(s)=%s$$\n',latex(symPol));
fprintf(fileID,'%%\n');

fclose(fileID);

myDoc = publish("testPublishLaTeX.m","html");

Now, I can view in the browser the file testPublishLaTeX.html, just created with the publish command.
